# How to install pytorch 1.2.0 with CUDA support on Windows 10?

Tags: python, installation, pip, pytorch

I'm trying to install pytorch 1.2.0 with CUDA support on Windows 10 with Python 3.9 and it keeps erroring out.

For example, I do `pip install pytorch==1.2.0 torchvision==0.4.0 cudatoolkit=10.0 -c pytorch`

and get:

`ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pytorch'`

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Check https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/ and look in the page for `torch==1.2.0`. Depending on your CUDA version you should find the package you need (it's `torch` though!)

Comment: I tried all of the Windows ones under 1.2.0 except Conda now. Still errors unfortunately. Example, when I do `pip install torch==1.2.0 torchvision==0.4.0` I get `Could not find a version that satisfied the requirement torch==1.2.0 Error: No matching distribution found for torch==1.2.0"` =(

Comment: What is `-c pytorch`?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. It is just part of the suggested command from https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/ (Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/YNZWFxt.png) I will keep digging.

Comment: OK careful as that screenshot is using `conda`, not `pip`.

Answer (score 1):

My answer:

`pip install wheel`

And then use the version link from here:
https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-370/

For example, if you want 1.1.0 for Python 3.7 Windows, do:

`pip install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu100/torch-1.1.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`

Thank you all